# how to sortby the result of countby data laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i need to view on blade most popular categories from products table by collecting products and make count of categories of them and sorting result to arrange them desc

```
    $popular_channels = products::select('category')->get();

    $collection = collect($popular_products);
    $counted = $collection->countBy(function ($value){
        return $value['category'];
    });

    $sorted = array_values(Arr::sort($counted, function ($values) {
        return $values['category'];
    }));
    $counted = json_decode($counted,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    $popular = channels::query();

    foreach ($counted as $key=>$value)
    {
        $popular = $popular->where('id', $key);
    }
    $popular = $popular->offset(0)->limit(3)->orderby('id','desc')->get();
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output? Also can you provide the relationships so that we can build the query for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from my solution, your code has still some points unclear to me:

- why do you create an array called `$popular_channels` as you are working on categories, then on the last few lines you introduce the channel model in a `$popular` array?
- what's the purpose of `$sorted` array?
- you are plucking popular `categories` id and then filtering `channels` on the id column with ids from the category table. Are these related or connected in any manner?

And a couple of notes that might be helpful:

- The `get` method returns a `collection` instance, so you don't really need to call the `collect` method
- ordering by id (last line of code) would lead the results sorted by the table id, not by the popular category ids you retrieved in the first place.
- I think you are trying to filter the channels only by the popular IDs you have found at the first step, instead of iterating through the counted array, you might as well use `whereIn($field, $keys)`

#### Solution Attempt derived from the code

To answer correctly and completely maybe you should put excerpt from your migrations/DB structure and model classes, but with a bit of tweaking (column names, table names, models, typos, etc), this query should do it:

```php
$populars = DB::table('products')
    ->selectRaw('category_id, count(*) as productsCount'))
    ->groupBy('category_id')
    ->orderBy('productsCount', 'desc')
    ->limit(3)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

$channels = Channels::whereIn('id', $populars)
    ->orderByRaw('FIELD(id,' . implode(',', $populars) . ')') // Preserve the ID order as retrieved before
    ->get();
```